# Saving and retrieving background images automatically on application start up

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 application, i created a button that can change backround on no. of counts. By default am having a background image. What i need is, if the user changed the background(using the above button), i want that image should be saved or remembered by isolated storage. And then when the app is launched again, that particular image(which was chosen by the user last time) should be the background image of my app. Now the problem is, am not able to retrieve images(but am able to save it), and dont know how to put that image as background image automatically on the app launch(don't want to use any button to save or retrieve,must be automatic). Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot for your hard work!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string imguri = "";

        click_count = click_count % 4;
        switch (click_count)
        {
            case 0: imguri = "Images/image4.png"; break;
            case 1: imguri = "Images/image3.jpg"; break;
            case 2: imguri = "Images/image2.png"; break;
            case 3: imguri = "Images/image1.jpg"; break;

        }
        click_count++;

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imguri, UriKind.Relative));
        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
        imageBrush.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
        var app = Application.Current as App;
        this.LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;
        app.appbrush = imageBrush;
        app.backchanged = true;

        string filename = "Images/app.jpg";
        StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));

        bitmapImage.SetSource(sr.Stream);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Images");

            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(filename))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(filename);
            }
            IsolatedStorageFileStream filestream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(filename);
            Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, filestream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            filestream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for loading image and assign it to background:

```
IsolatedStorageFile Store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (Store.FileExists("Images/app.jpg"))
{
    try
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream Stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, Store))
        {
            if (Stream.Length > 0)
            {
                BitmapImage Image = new BitmapImage();
                Image.SetSource(Stream);
                this.LayoutRoot.Background = Image;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {            
    }
}
```

Comment: Where to put the your codes to load that image automatically when the app is launches?